# Angular2 Get data from HTML data- attribute to component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have issue with getting data from HTML data attr to component.

In Template I have:

```
<button [attr.data-direction]="next" type="text" (click)="nextNotes()" [disabled]="checkPage(paginator)"> > </button>
```

And how can I call this data attr in class method after click? There is some ng workflow for that or purejs?

```
console.log(data)
```

Comment: you want to get the **data-direction** attribute ? try with this `<button #myBtn ...`, then in your TS class you can retrieve the attribute with `myBtn.getAttribute('data-direction')`

Comment: But what type has variable myBtn?

Comment: `ElementRef`, you can retrieve it like this `constructor(myBtn: ElementRef) { ... }`, then you can try with `myBtn.nativeElement.getAttribute(...)`

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I am 100 % capish here, but if you just want the value from `data-directive`, then you could pass the button as a local variable to `nextNotes()` and retrieve the value from there using `getAttribute`

Template:

```
<button #btn data-direction="next" type="text" (click)="nextNotes(btn)" [disabled]="checkPage(paginator)"></button>
```

Class method:

```
nextNotes(val) {
  console.log(val.getAttribute('data-direction'))
}
```